# special characters ç,ã display as � in HTML

Tags: html

I am adding special characters *ç,ã* in my HTML and these displays as �.

I am also using utf-8 in my HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Please suggest me how to display these special characters in HTML.

Comment: make sure your html file is saved as `UTF-8`. check your editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [HTML escape Tool](http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html)

### ç,ã

```
<span>&ccedil;,&atilde; </span>
```

Comment: This hides the symptoms but does not solve the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass HTML code for this specific special character.

for example:

`ç` = `&ccedil;`

`ã` =  `&atilde;`

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ofjvjvka/)

for more special charactere's code check this http://www.starr.net/is/type/htmlcodes.html